# How to set delay in camel route

Tags: apache-camel, jms, osgi

I'm using camel OSGi blueprint. I'm trying to set delay in camel route. The following is my code:

```
<camelContext id="Details"  xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
    <threadPoolProfile id="defaultThreadPoolProfile" defaultProfile="true"
               poolSize="50" maxPoolSize="150" maxQueueSize="-1" allowCoreThreadTimeOut="false"
               rejectedPolicy="CallerRuns"/>

    <route id="Test" delayer="30000">
        <from uri="vm://testDetails?multipleConsumers=true&amp;concurrentConsumers=20" />
        <bean ref="Location" method="getDetails" />
    </route>    

    <route id="Test2">
        <from uri="vm://testDetails1?multipleConsumers=true&amp;concurrentConsumers=20" />
        <delay> 
            <constant>1000</constant>
        </delay>
        <bean ref="Location" method="getDetails" />
    </route>   

</camelContext>
```

The above routes did not work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which route calls these vm routes? How vm end points trigger in with this CamelContext?

Comment: Did not work at all? Or the delay aspect did not work?

Comment: @Jayaraj: I have a bean after camelcontext `<bean id="Location" class="com.test.location" />`

Comment: @Darius: Only the delay aspect doesn't work

Comment: Everything looks fine, there should be a delay of one second (route id = "Test2").

Comment: @AlexeyYakunin: Yes, but the delay did not work.